# How to pass json content to python subprocess or json file

Tags: python, json, linux, subprocess, openshift

I am using python subprocess.popen to run openshift command.

My subprocess.popen looks like:

```
subprocess.Popen(['oc','create','-n',project,'-f','resource.json'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I am trying to pass json file like this. But it's not creating resource that I am trying to create.
Do anyone know any other way I can pass json content to it.

Answer (score 0):

As OpenShift is Kubernetes, it might be a worth checking if you want to use the Python Kubernetes client to interact with OpenShift: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python

Your code using `subprocess` looks correct, so check what is printed in `stdout` and `stderr`:

```
import subprocess

project = 'simon'
process = subprocess.Popen(['oc','create','-n',project,'-f','resource.json'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in process.stderr:
    print(line.strip())

for line in process.stdout:
    print(line.strip())
```

So for example:

```
$ python3 test.py
b'pod/test created'
$ python3 test.py
b'Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "resource.json": pods "test" already exists'
```